# Hide numbers on an axis on recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have a chart where the X axis shows numbers, but I only want this numbers show on the tooltip, not in the axis. What I mean is the numbers 3, 5, 4 shouldn't be displayed. The problem is that if I hide the axis then the text *Labels* doesn't show.

[image]

```
<XAxis dataKey="x">
    <Label value="Labels" position="bottom" />
</XAxis>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `tick={false}` as a prop to `<XAxis>` component, in your case:

```
<XAxis dataKey="x" tick={false}>
    <Label value="Labels" position="bottom" />
</XAxis>
```

[Docs](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/XAxis#tick)

[JSFiddle Example without X axis values(ticks)](https://jsfiddle.net/ceazut59/)

Comment: Oh, I did not know they were called ticks so I didn't find that info in the docs. Thank you!